# ios inapp purchase receipt

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

ios in-app purchase how to know this product has been purchased already ( i can check this by `nsuserdefault` locally but how to know after remove app from phone then re-install app )

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Chapters/ValidateRemotely.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010573-CH104-SW1

Comment: You must provide a restore purchases button. This will allow the user to restore non-consumable and subscription type purchases.

Comment: Go through [this](https://www.raywenderlich.com/36270/in-app-purchases-non-renewing-subscription-tutorial)

Comment: @ Paulw11 thanks friend, i used it but how i know this purchase by same app id (or this purchase by this particular phone)

Comment: You don't care about the device. The purchase is for the Apple ID. The user can restore their purchases on any device.

Comment: @paulw11 thanks got it now, but in receipt which i stored there is no Apple ID  which i parsed https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Chapters/ValidateRemotely.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010573-CH104-SW1

Comment: That's right. You don't get to know the users Apple ID. When you restore purchases the user is promoted to authenticate and then the purchase information is delivered to your payment queue delegate; you process it exactly the same as the original purchase

Comment: @ Paulw11 thanks friend,  i got exact output as i need.

Answer (score 1):

You can the receipt in this way (from  [Read the Receipt Data](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Chapters/ValidateRemotely.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010573-CH104-SW1)):

```
// Load the receipt from the app bundle.
NSURL *receiptURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] appStoreReceiptURL];
NSData *receipt = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:receiptURL];
if (!receipt) { /* No local receipt -- handle the error. */ }
```

If the user deleted the app, you have to provide a way to restore the purchase.

You can do something like this:

```
- (IBAction)restorePurchase:(id)sender{
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:self];
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] restoreCompletedTransactions];
}

// Then this is called
- (void)paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue {

    NSMutableArray *purchasedItemIDs = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for (SKPaymentTransaction *transaction in queue.transactions) {
        NSString *productID = transaction.payment.productIdentifier;
        [purchasedItemIDs addObject:productID];
        NSLog(@"product id is %@", productID);
    }  
}
```